# XBee Arduino API Remote At Command Response

Tags: arduino, xbee

I'm in trouble with programming my Arduino. I've two XBee Series 2 Modules and an Arduino UNO. I use the XBee-API library from: http://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/.
I generate three RemoteATRequest Packets (0x17) to control a Digital Pin of the Remote Sleepy Node and send it out of a SoftwareSerial to the XBee Coordinator which is plugged via a Sparkfun XBee Arduino Shield (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10854) to the Arduino UNO. The Communication works fine. Every Request Packet is sending out to the Remote. And for every Request Packet a Remote Packet is received. I checked this with a Serial Monitor and a RS232<-> TTL Converter. But in my Arduino Software it seems to be that only one Remote Packet is received. Curious is the point that when I send the Request Packets in the time the Remote is sleeping than I read three Response if it is awake and takes the Requests from the Coordinator.

Does anyone try the same or hase the same problems? I've tried so much until know another Baudrate, delays befor sending out. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

My recollection of ZigBee and/or 802.15.4 is that the parent node for a sleepy end device will only hold/queue a single frame for when the sleepy device wakes up.  And note that in ZigBee it's only guaranteed to queue it for 7.5 seconds.  You may need to modify your code to send a single Remote AT Request at a time, and wait for the response before sending another.

[This page](http://www.freaklabs.org/index.php/Blog/Zigbee/Page-6.html) has a good description about how the MAC layer works:

> Once the frame is assembled, there are actually two ways to send it.
>   If its going to another router or an end device whose receiver is
>   always on, the frame will be sent directly via the radio. Otherwise,
>   if the destination is a sleepy end device, the frame will need to be
>   sent as an indirect transfer. The frame will go to the indirect queue
>   until the destination device wakes up and polls the parent. Once the
>   poll comes in, the frame will get sent to the destination.

It would be great if the XBee module supported a frame type that contains multiple AT commands, but as far as I can tell, that isn't an option.